# FBX export issue

Tags: export, .fbx

Hi I'm trying with no success at all to export a FBX file from my blend file with texture
Uv are made .
I already select "copy" on path mode.
I also check the embed texture button.

I try on blender 2.93.5 (and also on blender 3.10) no succes at all
After I checked my FBX file with mixer / 3ds max / blender / etc no texture with it empty blank mesh ...

[image]

Comment: okay thx I understand like its not possible to add texture on a fbx but how come on this video the guy succed ? https://gamedevtraum.com/en/blender-2-8-en/how-to-export-a-3d-model-in-fbx-format-with-textures-in-blender/

Comment: https://youtu.be/WLQoOdUqrHs?t=685 also here they easily export with no problem ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEP34CbPWUo also here

Comment: It is not impossible to export materials, but you need to use a node setup that the FBX exporter supports, like is shown in [your video](https://youtu.be/WLQoOdUqrHs?t=15). See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html) for more info. Only VERY simple setups are supported. Your "mask" setup is too complicated.

Comment: @Marty Fouts I wish people would stop linking that answer. It basically says "it's impossible" and like OP observed, it obviously isn't.

Comment: Got it NOW thanks you @scurest yhea u so right . A simple setup work flawless U can add an answer I will green tick

Comment: @scurest  I misread that answer, and thought it was instructions to bake textures.  After reading your comment, I see I was in error.  I've deleted my comments pointing to it. Thanks.